# Why are my coffeescript functions not available from my HTML code ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scope, coffeescript, iced-coffeescript, coffeescript-resources

I am using rails-backbone, coffeescript gems in my rails 3.2.6 project.

`square = (x) -> x * x
alert square(5)`

this is the blog.js.coffee script file it produces:

`(function() {  var square; square = function(x) {return x * x;}; alert(square(5));`

I need to call the `square()` method in an other view file.

How can I call that? 
Is there any thing wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your code in Coffeescript will be inside a self-invoking anonymous function.

To call it outside a file, just write:

```
window.square = (x) -> x * x
```

`alert(square(5))` in an other function

The best you can do to not overuse window is a App object that will contain all your variables.

```
window.App={}
window.App.square=  (x) -> x * x
```

and then `alert(App.square(5))`

Comment: What is Self-anonymous function?

Comment: A self invoking anonymous function is a function that has no name (**hence anonymous**) and that calls itself. It is used to protect the code from being accessed from the outside of the function. Here's a specifi question about this.

Answer (score -1):

Call it like a regular JavaScript function:

```
<script>    
  square(5)
</script>
```

Comment: This won't work as there won't be a `square` function in scope.